# Pharo: Retractable Panel in Glamour Browser. How?

Tags: user-interface, browser, pharo

I am building a Glamour presentation which is divided into two panes: one displaying a timetable and another pane showing the details for the event the user has clicked on.

If the user removes the selection, I'd like to retract the details pane so that there is more room for the timetable.

I have looked at GLMFinder which sort of does dynamic space allocation, but only initially when there is no selection. Is there a simple way to do this? Or do I have to write a custom renderer?